# How to query more fields on mongo DB aggregation query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I would like to know how to add an extra field to the response of **collection.aggregate**?

The query below groups activities by **user_id**. And I would like to know how to also include the user_name in the response.

**DB Models**

```
class Activity
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :hd_race_id, type: Float
  field :metric_elapsed_time, type: Float
  field :metric_distance, type: Float
  field :user_name, type: String
  belongs_to :user
  ...


class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :user_name, type: String
  has_many :activities
  ...
```

**Query**

```
Activity.collection.aggregate([          
      {
        "$group" => {
          "_id" => "$user_id",
          "distance" => { "$sum" => "$metric_distance" },
          "time" => { "$sum" => "$metric_elapsed_time" },
        },
      },
      { "$sort" => { "distance" => -1 } },          
    ])
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the operator [**$first** (aggregation accumulator)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) inside the *$group* stage.

For example:

> ```
> "user_name": {"$first": "$user_name"}
> ```

or for the programming language you are using (not sure what it is), try something like:

> ```
> "user_name" => {"$first" => "$user_name"},
> ```

For an example, see the "Group & Total" chapter in my [Practical MongoDB Aggregations book](https://www.practical-mongodb-aggregations.com/examples/foundational/group-and-total.html)